# Image pre-processing for better accuracy in OCR

Tags: image, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, image-preprocessing

I am using Gaussian kernel for image enhancements in OpenCV with 250% enlagrement:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread("test.png")
small = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=2.5, fy=2.5)

img = small

kernel_sharpen_3 = np.array([[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
                             [-1,2,2,2,-1],
                             [-1,2,8,2,-1],
                             [-1,2,2,2,-1],
                             [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]]) / 8.0

output_3 = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel_sharpen_3)

cv2.imwrite('enhancement.png', output_3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But still doesn't give very good results. What other preprocessing should I do to improve the accuracy? I am using [ocr.space](https://ocr.space/) as a tool.

Some examples:

[image: Image1]
**Language English:**

- It incorrectly detected **KIHC US** as **KI-IC US**

[image: Image2]
**Language English:**

- It incorrectly detected **HRL US** as **HRI- US**  (second last row)

[image: Image3]
**Language English:**

- It didn't detect **BN FP**

[image: Image4]
**Language English:**

- It incorrectly detected **HPQ US** as **I-IPQ US** (But it has correctly detected H in HEN3 GR in the next row)
- It incorrectly detected **LALAB MM** as **I-ALAB MM**
- It didn't detect **RB/ LN**

Comment: If you want folks to be able to help you. I think you should provide more details about your results (i.e. result images) and the steps / algorithms / libraries you used to achieve your OCR.